# Find the value of a constant from the CDF?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

The question I'm having trouble with is:

A continuous random variable has the CDF:

$\hspace{10mm} F(x) =  \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 
0 & & x < 0 \\
cx^2 & &0 \leq x \leq 2 \\
1 & & x > 2  \end{array}\right\}$

Find the value of the positive constant $c$.

I understand that to get $c$ from a pdf, a simple integral is all it takes. However, it is escaping me on how to get $c$ from a CDF. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The CDF must be continuous.

The only possible problem is at $x=2$, to make it continuous there you need $4c=1$ and hence $c=\frac14$.

Comment: Wow, can't believe it was that simple.... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The essential point is that it says "continuous".  There is only one value of $c$ that makes this function continuous at the point where $x=2$.